# cookies are determined only on the pages where they were set

Tags: php, cookies

I have a big website using mvc pattern, it's a little bit hard to give details with links and stuff, but I want to ask a simple question.

When I set cookies like this `setcookie("countviews_interview_downloads_1",'1',$this->registry->config['countviews_cookie_lifetime']);`

And then check like this:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['countviews_interview_downloads_1']))
{
  print('msg: cookie is on interview #1');
  exit;
}
```

A message appears that `msg: cookie is on interview #1` only on the page where it has been set.

If I put this above code that checks for cookie on anyther page it does not appear, behaves like it has never been set.

Help me out please. THANKS!.

Comment: What kind of ‘pages’ are you referring to?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by what kind of pages am I referring. Cookie is being set on `/interview/christmas/countdownloads`, if I put a check code on this page then message shows that cookie is set, but if i put a check code on page `/interview` or `/interview/christmas/` or `/` or elsewhere message doesn't show up. seems like it is being set only for that page of website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don’t specify any path for the cookie, a cookie is only valid for the same path. In your case that will be `/interview/christmas/countdownloads`. So just set the cookie’s path to `/` and it will be present for all other paths:

```
setcookie("countviews_interview_downloads_1",'1',$this->registry->config['countviews_cookie_lifetime'], '/')
```

Comment: hmm. now it worked, but i tried it before and it did not work, maybe because i also indicated domain? okay, i'll keep it. thank you very much. i'll accept your answer asasp.

Comment: @tmpmember No, specifying the domain is not necessary. Again, the issuing domain is used if not explicitly specified.